# Browse files through bluez

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez, obex

I want to create an app in Linux that can browse the files from a bluetooth phone and eventually retrieve them. I've been reading and googling and it seems the way to do it is communicating with Bluez via DBus.

However there doesn't seem to be DBus methods for interacting with files. Therefore, do I need to use obex protocol to do this instead? I'm quite lost here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case you want to use FTP profile which uses obex protocol,this obex will call RFCOMM layer and thus bluetooth will be used.You need to create a filetransfer(org.bluez.obex.FileTransfer) interface and call obex methods via dbus call,check [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/obex-api.txt) or the ftp plugin available in bluez